# Ask for five values, subtract the lowest and take the average

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with this python code that is supposed to ask for five values, find the minimum value and subtract it and find the average of the remaining four numbers. I want to use a for loop and if anyone can help me also create a list, i can't seem to get that to work either so I'm doing it as you see below

```
def get_data():
    name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
    for i in range(5):
            scores = int(input("what are your test scores? ")
    return name, scores

def low_score(scores):
    low = min(scores)
    print low
    return low, scores

def find_avg(scores, low):
    avg = sum(scores)
    print name, "your average = ", avg
    return avg 

name, scores = get_data()
low, scores = low_score(scores)
avg = find_avg(scores, low)
```

Comment: i'm getting a syntax error

Comment: You are missing the *subtraxt the lowest value* part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your approach.  Take a look at this while I write some comments:

```
def get_data():
    name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
    scores = []
    for i in range(5):
        scores.append(int(input("what are your test scores? ")))
    return name, scores

def drop_low_score(scores):
    sorted_scores = sorted(scores)
    print "Dropping", sorted_scores[0]
    highest_four_scores = sorted_scores[1:]
    return scores

def find_avg(scores):
    avg = sum(scores) / float(len(scores))
    print name, "your average = ", avg
    return avg

name, scores = get_data()
scores = drop_low_score(scores)
avg = find_avg(scores)
```

When you assign the value from input to score, you are overwriting it each time.  Here I am appending it to a list I create before the loop.

Think of it like this:

```
scores = []
for i in range(5):
    new_score = int(input("test score?"))
    scores.append(new_score)
```

Each time through the loop you are appending a new value to the list of scores.  At the end of the loop you have 5 scores in your list.

The next problem is you are getting the low_score, but you are doing nothing with it.  There  are a few ways to deal with that.  Read about `list` to find ways to do it.  In my code (since the list is so small) I simply sort it and slice the list, cutting off the first one after it is sorted (default sorting is small to large), so it removes the smallest value.  You can read up on list slicing too, but this is an example,

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print my_list[2:]
[3, 4]
>>> print my_list[3:]
[4]
>>> print my_list[:2]
[1, 2]
```

The last problem is your `find_avg` which doesn't find an average at all, it is just summing the scores.  You need to sum and divide by the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing bracket in the line -

```
scores = int(input("what are your test scores? ")
```

I'm *guessing* that's the source of your problem because you haven't provided any traceback.

Comment: yeah that made it run! but im getting a new error now:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\Lab7 (2).py", line 16, in <module>
    name, scores = get_data()
  File "C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\Lab7 (2).py", line 3, in get_data
    for i in range [5]:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 0):

In your loop

```
for i in range(5):
        scores = int(input("what are your test scores? ")
```

you are overwriting `scores` five times, without saving the previous values.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
scores = [int(input("what are your test scores? ") for _ in range(5)]
```

So the whole assignment would boil down to:

```
scores = [int(input("what are your test scores? ") for _ in range(5)]
print('Your top four average is', (sum(scores)-min(scores))/4.0)
```

Comment: how do i not overwrite them? sorry i'm trying to teach myself

Comment: @user3317056 Look at the second code snippet I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def get_data():
    name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
    scores = []
    for i in range(5):
        scores.append(int(input("what are your test scores? ")))
    return name, scores

def low_score(scores):
    low = min(scores)
    print low
    return low, scores

def find_avg(scores, low):
    indvalue = scores.index(low)
    scores.pop(indvalue)
    avg = sum(scores)/len(scores)
    print name, "your average = ", avg
    return avg 

name, scores = get_data()
low, scores = low_score(scores)
avg = find_avg(scores, low)
```

the above code should wrk fine... with minor modifications in your logic